# WPF designtime parsing is different

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm having an issue where my MarkupExtension is behaving differently at designtime, or rather the xaml parser is providing different values.

my class:

```
class FormattableConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public FormattableConverter(string format)
    {
        Format = format;
    }

    public string Format { get; set; }

    public override void ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var formattable = value as IFormattable;
        return formattable?.ToString(Format, culture);
    }

    /* ConvertBack returns NotImplementedException */
}
```

I'm using it to show a `DateTime` value.:

```
<HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding DateTimeValue, Converter={c:FormattableConverter 'hh\\:mm\\:ss'}}"
                        /* Other parameters */ />
```

When breaking during runtime, IntelliSense shows the format is *hh\\:mm\\:ss*, and formatting works.

But in the designer a FormatException is thrown: `Input string was not in a correct format.`

If i debug the designer (Attaching to XDesProc.exe) IntelliSence show me that the format is *hh:mm:ss*; The backslashes are gone.

I've tried:

- `'hh\\:mm\\:ss'`
- `'hh&#92;&#92;:mm&#92;&#92;:ss'`
- `{}hh\\:mm\\:ss`
- `Format='hh\\\\:mm\\\\:ss'` (this works in designer, but not runtime)
- `Format=hh\\\\:mm\\\\:ss` (this works in designer, but not runtime)
- `Format=hh\\:mm\\:ss`
- other combinations of above

Any idea why the parser provides different string values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

On the top of your UserControl/Window:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:FormattableConverter x:Key="formattableConverter" />
    <sys:String x:Key="myParameter"> hh\\:mm\\:ss </sys:String>
</Window.Resources>
```

and then in the control:

```
<HeaderedContentControl Content="{Binding DateTimeVale, 
                                          Converter={StaticResource formattableConverter} 
                                          ConverterParameter={StaticResource myParameter}}">

</HeaderedContentControl>
```

Still if you have any problems, then please post a sample project.

Comment: I've just tried changing my converter to use the ConverterParameter instead of a property, and doing this: `ConverterParameter="hh\:mm\:ss"`. This works! Also by moving the format string to a resource also works. Apparently the parser does not like to parse to custom properties.